# Practice SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I wanted a website that has ample amount of SQL (SQL Server 2005 or 2008) related queries to practice at home

Please let me know if you have any idea about the same.

thanks

Comment: Expecting more solutions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one: [SQL exercises](http://www.sql-ex.ru/). The queries are of different difficult from easy to hardest.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest you to practice using Stack Exchange Data Explorer at https://data.stackexchange.com

Select a StackExchange site and click Compose Query button.

> What is Stack Exchange Data Explorer?
>
> Stack Exchange Data Explorer allows
>   you to run arbitrary SQL queries on
>   the Stack Exchange family of sites,
>   share those queries with your friends
>   and explore interesting queries.

For more info, read the [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

I think few people know about this great site.

Comment: Yeah... really really cool. You can learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.sqltree.com/
Also, some sample databases can be found here: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

Comment: sqltree doesn't allow me to execute the queries nor it has Problems that i could practice and solve it and see whether the solution is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find a wealth of material here:

http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/

Comment: where could i practice SQL Queries? I don't want Sample Database

Comment: In order to practice queries the first thing you will need is data to run your queries on, hence the sample databases.  After that just start reading about different sql statements and trying them out on your sample data.

Comment: i already have sample db and that too downloaded from site given. If i was able to "start reading........" i wouldn't had posted the question here.. I am looking for site that allows me to practice real world SQL statements, no matter whether that's online/offline

Comment: have you tried the sql tutorials at w3shools?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

They have a web tool that lets you practice queries against a small dataset they have provided.

Answer (score 0):

You may use http://www.compileonline.com/execute_sql_online.php to execute your queries online.

Hope this helps.